# How to create a list of non duplicate numbers (Python)

Tags: python, random

So, I need a code for school where I need to generate 4 random numbers using randint and they can't be duplicates, I just cant seem to get my head around it. - Cheers

Comment: Hint: How would you do it with dice?

Comment: I'd imagine you'd do some higher/lower calculations, I've tried that and they don't work. :/

Comment: Throw a dice. If its number is equal to any of the other dice, throw it again.

Comment: @Rawing I'm glad _someone_ got my hint. ;)

Comment: @PM2Ring Well I think part of the OP's problem was that he was trying to over-complicate things. Maybe if you would have added a bit more to your hint stating not to over-think things, he might have got it.

Comment: Now I feel stupid. :/

Comment: @Lewis: No reason to feel stupid here. We all have made some mistakes that are not obvious to us at the time but become clear down the road.

Comment: Thanks Mountain Tech :) Just getting started, know the basics moving on to slightly more advanced now.

Comment: @PM2Ring _"It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction"_ - _Well, not necessarily_. You can still accept an answer even if your problem hasn't been solved to your satisfaction. I think the better definition would be to say: "It lets everyone know the answer which helped you the most in solving your problem". Sorry, I know I'm being picky-picky, but since the OP was new to the site, I didn't want him to become confused :-)

Comment: @ChristianDean Fair point. I didn't actually write that comment, I "borrowed" it from a very senior member and have it in a userscript. If it's good enough for him... :) However, I believe OPs _shouldn't_ accept an answer unless it resolves their problem. OTOH, just because an answer has the green checkmark, that doesn't mean it's the best answer, since the OP may not yet have the necessary expertise to make that judgement. But this is turning into a discusssion more suited to Meta SO. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `random.sample` to randomly select 4 elements from a list.

```
import random
low, high = 0, 1000
w, x, y, z = random.sample(range(low, high) , 4)
```

Set `low` and `high` to your desired range from where you want to sample numbers.

Here's a less wasteful solution using `randint` (sorry for not seeing this earlier), if you want to generate any number in a wide range.

```
numbers = set()
while len(numbers) < 4:
    num = random.randint(low, high)
    if num not in numbers:
        numbers.add(num)

w, x, y, z = numbers
```

Comment: @Lewis Try my second one and tell me how it goes.

Comment: Thanks coldspeed :)

Comment: @Lewis Cheers mate.

Answer (score 3):

We can accomplish a list of 4 random numbers by using a while loop to create a random number then append that number to a list only if that number does not already exist in the list. If we can append list then `x -= 1` until `x == 0` then the while loop will stop and the code will print out the list.

It will be different every time.

```
import random

x = 4
list_of_random_numbers = []
while x != 0:
    new_random_number = random.randint(0,999) # you can define any range of numbers here.
    if new_random_number not in list_of_random_numbers:
        list_of_random_numbers.append(new_random_number)
        x -= 1

print (list_of_random_numbers)
```

Edit:

Also as `PM 2Ring` said you can just check the length of the list as well:

```
import random

list_of_random_numbers = []
while len(list_of_random_numbers) < 4:
    new_random_number = random.randint(0,999) # you can define any range of numbers here.
    if new_random_number not in list_of_random_numbers:
        list_of_random_numbers.append(new_random_number)

print (list_of_random_numbers)
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm! :)

Comment: You might as well just check the length of the list rather than maintaining `x` to track the count. All of Python's standard collection types store their current length as an attribute, so calling `len` on them is very efficient. Using a list here is probably no slower than using a set (checking set membership is O(1), but checking list membership is O(n) because it requires a linear scan), but for larger collections, using a set will be faster.

Comment: @PM 2Ring: LoL... I was thinking the opposite for some reason... Been a long day.

Comment: Yours worked also, I would check them both but I had to go with one, sorry man, but great job and thank you :)

Comment: @PM 2Ring: WOOT! Thanks. I never thought I would make 1000 points in just under 4 months from the start of learning programming. I am excited :D

Comment: @Lewis: No worries. Always accept the answer that is best for you. If you like other answers as well you can always upvote late :)

Comment: Thanks for understanding :)

Comment: @SierraMountainTech Congrats on 1k!

Comment: @Coldspeed: Ty Ty. :D

Comment: @SierraMountainTech As other have already said, congrats on breaking the 1K mark! Be sure to check out [your new privileges as well](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) ;-)

Comment: @Lewis: its fun to set goals to earn interesting [Privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)

Comment: @Christian Dean: LoL I just posted same link.